# C++. Неправильное выделение динамической памяти. Ошибка.

Tags: c++

Доброе утро! Есть программа, которая хранит сведения о студентах. В ней реализовано 2 класса. 1 - класс группа 2 - студент. Всё работает: Запись всех сведений о студенте, добавление студента в группу, вывод всех данных на экран и т.п. Вот только не работает один метод - метод сортировки.
Например в случае если в дальнейшем я захочу реализовать поиск по фамилии студента, а студентов с такой фамилией окажется двое или трое к примеру. Вот и необходимым условием для выполнения задачи требуется реализовать метод сортировки по ФИО. Сам метод сравнения ФИО я сделал(перегрузил оператор > и < для фио). И метод сортировки тоже придумал. Но вот есть в нем одна ошибка:
метод работает по принципу пузырьковой сортировки
1. я создаю временный экземпляр класса "студент", в который перезаписываю экземпляр( в случае перестановки местами с экземпляром, у которого фио короче(ну в общем тот кто знает пузырьковую сортировку поймет))
2.и когда я начинаю менять местами экземпляры класса(например в экземпляр под индексом массива mas[0] я перезаписываю экземпляр под индексом mas[1]) - ПРОГРАММА ПАДАЕТ!!!!!!!=(

В общем я отследил отладчиком что падает на этапе когда очищается память свойств экземпляра (я перегрузил опрератор "=" для экземпляров - падает именно в нем, т.е. когда я присваиваю)
Не очищается память - это значит одно - СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО ОНА НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО ВЫДЕЛЯЕТСЯ ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО! Но я проверял в других методах она очищается нормально а вот в методе сортировки не выходит. Помогите решить эту проблему.
Вот код:
я прокомментирую где именно она не работает:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct date
{
    int day;
    char* month;
    int year;
};

class Student
{
public:
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    char* patronymic;
    date data;
    char* group;
    char* mail;
    char* adress;
    int tell;
    int icq;
    Student ()
    {

        name=NULL;
        surname=NULL;
        patronymic=NULL;
        data.month=NULL;
        group=NULL;
        mail=NULL;
        adress=NULL;
        tell=0;
        icq=0;
        data.day=0;
        data.year=0;
    }
    Student (char*_name,char* _surname,char* _patr,char* _mounth,char* _gr,char* _mail,char*_adr,
        int atell,int aicq,int dai,int _year)
    {

        name=new char[strlen (_name)+1];
        strcpy(name,_name);
        surname=new char [strlen(_surname)+1];
        strcpy(surname,_surname);
        patronymic=new char [strlen(_patr)+1];
        strcpy(patronymic,_patr);
        group=new char [strlen(_gr)+1];
        strcpy(group,_gr);
        adress=new char[strlen(_adr)+1];
        strcpy(adress,_adr);
        mail=new char [strlen(_mail)+1];
        strcpy(mail,_mail);
        data.day=dai;
        data.month=new char [strlen(_mounth)+1];
        strcpy(data.month,_mounth);
        data.year=_year;
        tell=atell;
        icq=aicq;
    }
    void set_name(char*aname)
    {

        if(name!=NULL)
            delete[] name;
        name=new char[strlen (aname)+1];
        strcpy(name,aname);
    }
    void set_surname(char* asurn)
    {
        if(surname!=0)
            delete[] surname;
        surname=new char[strlen (asurn)+1];
        strcpy(surname,asurn);

    }
    void set_patr(char* apatr)
    {
        if(patronymic!=0)
            delete[] patronymic;
        patronymic=new char[strlen (apatr)+1];
        strcpy(patronymic,apatr);
    }
    void set_month(char* month)
    {
        if(data.month!=0)
            delete[] data.month;
        data.month=new char[strlen (month)+1];
        strcpy(data.month,month);
    }
    void set_gr(char* grop)
    {
        if(group!=0)
            delete[] group;
        group=new char[strlen (grop)+1];
        strcpy(group,grop);
    }
    void set_mail(char* amail)
    {
        if(mail!=0)
            delete[] mail;
        mail=new char[strlen (amail)+1];
        strcpy(mail,amail);
    }
    void set_adr(char* adres)
    {
        if(adress!=0)
            delete[] adress;
        adress=new char[strlen (adres)+1];
        strcpy(adress,adres);
    }
    void set_tell(int atel)
    {
        tell=atel;
    }
    void set_icq(int aicq)
    {
        icq=aicq;
    }
    void set_day(int aday)
    {
        data.day=aday;
    }
    void set_year(int ayear)
    {
        data.year=ayear;
    }

    char* get_name(char* aname)
    {
        return name;
    }
    char* get_surname(char* asurname)
    {
        return surname;
    }
    char* get_patr(char* apatr)
    {
        return patronymic;
    }
    char* get_group(char* agroup)
    {
        return group;
    }
    char* get_mail(char* amail)
    {
        return mail;
    }
    char* get_adr(char* aadress)
    {
        return adress;
    }
    int get_data_day()
    {
        return data.day;

    }
    int get_data_year()
    {
        return data.year;
    }
    char* get_data_maonh()
    {
        return data.month;
    }

    int comparison(const Student& p)
    {
        int size1=strlen(name)+strlen(surname)+strlen(patronymic);
        int size2=strlen(p.name)+strlen(p.surname)+strlen(p.patronymic);
        char* str1=new char[size1+1];
        char* str2=new char[size2+1];
        strcpy(str1,name);
        strcat(str1,surname);
        strcat(str1,patronymic);
        str1[size1]='\0';

        strcpy(str2,p.name);
        strcat(str2,p.surname);
        strcat(str2,p.patronymic);
        str2[size2]='\0';
        int result=strcmp(str1,str2);
        delete[] str1;
        delete[] str2;
        return result;

    }
    void operator =(const Student& p) //ВОТ ПЕРЕГРУЗКА ОПЕРАТОРА ПРИСВАИВАНИЯ В КОТОРОМ СОБСТВЕННО 
    {                                             //И ПРОБЛЕМА
        if(name!=NULL)
            delete[] name;//  <- ВОТ В ЭТОЙ СТРОЧКЕ ПРОГРАММА ПАДАЕТ(Т.Е. КОГДА НАДО СТЕРЕТЬ ДАННЫЕ ИЗ 
        name=new char[strlen(p.name+1)];//ИЗ СВОЙСТВА HELLLPPP!!!
        strcpy(name,p.name);

        if(surname!=NULL)
        {
            delete[] surname;
        }
        surname=new char[strlen(p.surname+1)];
        strcpy(surname,p.surname);

        if(patronymic!=NULL)
        {
            delete[] patronymic;
        }
        patronymic=new char[strlen(p.patronymic+1)];
        strcpy(patronymic,p.patronymic);
        if(data.month!=NULL)
        {
            delete[]data.month;
        }
        data.month=new char[strlen(p.data.month+1)];
        strcpy(data.month,p.data.month);
        if(group!=NULL)
        {

            delete[]group;
        }
        group=new char[strlen(p.group+1)];
        strcpy(group,p.group);

        if(adress!=NULL)
        {
            delete[]adress;
        }
        adress=new char[strlen(p.adress+1)];
        strcpy(adress,p.adress);

        if(mail!=NULL)
        {
            delete[] mail;
        }
        mail=new char[strlen(p.mail+1)];
        strcpy(mail,p.mail);
        data.day=p.data.day;
        data.year=p.data.year;
        tell=p.tell;
        icq=p.icq;
    }

    bool operator ==(const Student& p)
    {
        if (strcmp(name,p.name)==NULL)
            if (strcmp(surname,p.surname)==NULL)
                if (strcmp(patronymic,p.patronymic)==NULL)
                    if (strcmp(data.month,p.data.month)==NULL)
                        if (strcmp(group,p.group)==NULL)
                            if (strcmp(adress,p.adress)==NULL)
                                if (strcmp(mail,p.mail)==NULL)
                                    if(data.day==p.data.day)
                                        if(data.year==p.data.year)
                                            if(tell==p.tell)
                                                if(icq==p.icq)
                                                    return true;
                                                else return false;

    }

    bool operator !=(const Student& p)
    {
        if (strcmp(name,p.name)!=NULL)
            if (strcmp(surname,p.surname)!=NULL)
                if (strcmp(patronymic,p.patronymic)!=NULL)
                    if (strcmp(data.month,p.data.month)!=NULL)
                        if (strcmp(group,p.group)!=NULL)
                            if (strcmp(adress,p.adress)!=NULL)
                                if (strcmp(mail,p.mail)!=NULL)
                                    if(data.day!=p.data.day)
                                        if(data.year!=p.data.year)
                                            if(tell!=p.tell)
                                                if(icq!=p.icq)
                                                    return true;
                                                else return false;

    }

    bool operator <(const Student &p)
    {
        return ((comparison(p)<0)?true:false);
    }

    bool operator >(const Student &p)
    {
        return ((comparison(p)>0)?true:false);
    }

    void print_gr(const Student &Ex)
    {

        cout<<"GROUP :"<<Ex.name<<endl;
        cout<<Ex.surname<<","<<Ex.name<<","<<Ex.patronymic<<endl;
        cout<<Ex.data.day<<"."<<Ex.data.month<<"."<<Ex.data.year<<endl;
        cout<<Ex.adress<<endl;
        cout<<Ex.mail<<endl;
        cout<<"NOMBER ICQ"<<Ex.icq;
        cout<<"tell"<<Ex.tell;
        cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;

    }

    void file_man(FILE *afp) //метод записи всех пользователей в бинарный файл
{

    int sz = strlen(name);
    fwrite(&sz,sizeof(sz),1,afp);
    fwrite(name,sz,1,afp);
    int sz1 = strlen(surname);
    fwrite(&sz1,sizeof(sz1),1,afp);
    fwrite(surname,sz1,1,afp);
    int sz2 = strlen(patronymic);
    fwrite(&sz2,sizeof(sz2),1,afp);
    fwrite(patronymic,sz2,1,afp);
    int sz5 = strlen(adress);
    fwrite(&sz5,sizeof(sz5),1,afp);
    fwrite(adress,sz5,1,afp);
    int sz6 = strlen(group);
    fwrite(&sz6,sizeof(sz6),1,afp);
    fwrite(group,sz6,1,afp);
    int sz3 = strlen(mail);
    fwrite(&sz3,sizeof(sz3),1,afp);
    fwrite(mail,sz3,1,afp);
    fwrite(&tell,sizeof (tell),1,afp); 
    fwrite(&icq,sizeof (icq),1,afp);
    fwrite(&data.day,sizeof (data.day),1,afp);
    int sz4 = strlen(data.month);
    fwrite(&sz4,sizeof(sz4),1,afp);
    fwrite(data.month,sz4,1,afp);
    fwrite(&data.year,sizeof (data.year),1,afp);

}

    ~Student()
    {
        delete[]name;
        delete[]surname;
        delete[]patronymic;
        delete[]group;
        delete[]data.month;
        delete[]adress;
        delete[]mail;
    }

};
class Group
{
public:
    int size;
    Student* _student;

    Group()
    {
        size=0;
        Student* _student=NULL;
    }

    /*Group(char* aname,char* asurname,char* apatronymic,int aday,char* amonth,int ayear,
    char* agroup,char aadress,char* amail,int atell,int aicq)
    {

    }*/

    Group(Student &p)
    {
        size = 1;
        _student= new Student[size];
        _student[size - 1] = p;

    }

    void add(char* aname,char* asurname,char* apatronym,char* agrop,char* aadres,char* amail,int aday,char* amouth,
        int ayear,int atell,int aicq)
    {

        size++;
        if(size<2)
        {
            _student=new Student [size];

            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {

                _student[i].set_name(aname);
                _student[i].set_surname(asurname);
                _student[i].set_patr(apatronym);
                _student[i].set_gr(agrop);
                _student[i].set_adr(aadres);
                _student[i].set_mail(amail);
                _student[i].set_day(aday);
                _student[i].set_month(amouth);
                _student[i].set_year(ayear);
                _student[i].set_icq(aicq);
                _student[i].set_tell(atell);
            }

        }

        else if (size>1)
        {
            Student* mas=new Student[size];
            for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
            {
                mas[i]=_student[i];
            }
            mas[size-1].set_name(aname);
            mas[size-1].set_surname(asurname);
            mas[size-1].set_patr(apatronym);
            mas[size-1].data.day=aday;
            mas[size-1].set_month(amouth);
            mas[size-1].data.year=ayear;
            mas[size-1].set_gr(agrop);
            mas[size-1].set_adr(aadres);
            mas[size-1].set_mail(amail);
            mas[size-1].set_icq(aicq);
            mas[size-1].set_tell(atell);
            _student=new Student[size];
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                _student[i]=mas[i];
            }

        }
    }
    Student operator [](int i)
    {
        if (i<size&&i>-1)
            return _student[i];

    }

    void sorting() // вот этот метод сортировки по фио
    {
        Student temp;
        for(int i = 1; i < size;i++)
        {
            for(int j = i; j < size; j++)
            {
                if(_student[i - 1] > _student[j])
                {
                    temp = _student[i - 1];
                    _student[i - 1] = _student[j]; // <- вот здесь падает когда необходимо перезаписать одно 
                    _student[j] = temp;               // свойство в другое
                }
            }

        }
    }

};
void main()
{

    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    char patronym[100];
    char grop[50];
    char adres[200];
    char mail [200];
    int tell;
    int icq;
    int day;
    int year;
    char month[20];
    int k=1;
    bool y=true;
    Group gr20c31;

    while(y)
    {
        int j;
        printf("***********Please choose a necessary point**************\n");
        printf("1-add student\n2-to show out information about a student\n"
            "3--add to binary file\n4-exit\n");

        cin>>j;
        switch (j)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                cout << "___________Please add student:\n";

                cout<<"******person number"<<k<<" *****\n";

                cout<<"please enter surname=";
                cin>>surname;

                cout<<"please enter name=";
                cin>>name;
                cout<<"please enter patronymic=";
                cin>>patronym;
                cout<<"please enter group\n";
                cin>>grop;
                cout<<"please enter adress:";
                cin>>adres;
                cout<<"please enter email=";
                cin>>mail;
                cout<<"please enter birsday=";
                cin>>day;
                cout<<"please enter month of birth=";
            cin>>month;
                cout<<"please enter year of birth=";
                cin>>year;
                cout<<"please enter telephone of user number=";
                cin>>tell;

                cout<<"please enter ICQ of user number=";
                cin>>icq;

                gr20c31.add(name,surname,patronym,grop,adres,mail,day,month,year,tell,icq);
                cout<<"------------------------------------------------------\n";
                k++;

            }
            break;
        case 2:
            gr20c31.sorting();
            for(int i=0;i<gr20c31.size;i++)
            {

                cout<<gr20c31._student[i].group<<endl;
                cout<<gr20c31._student[i].surname<<"."<<gr20c31._student[i].name<<"."<<gr20c31._student[i].patronymic<<endl;
                cout<<gr20c31._student[i].data.day<<":"<<gr20c31._student[i].data.month<<":"<<gr20c31._student[i].data.year<<endl;
                cout<<gr20c31._student[i].adress<<endl;
                cout<<gr20c31._student[i].mail<<endl;
                cout<< gr20c31._student[i].icq<<endl;
                cout<<gr20c31._student[i].tell<<endl;
                cout<<"\n\n";

            }

            break;

            case 3:                             //запись в бинарный файл динамического массива экземпляров класса person
            {
                FILE *fp=fopen("first.txt","wb");
                if (!fp)
                {
                    cout<<"error";
                    _getch();   
                    return;
                }
                for (int i=0;i<gr20c31.size;i++)
                {
                    gr20c31._student[i].file_man(fp);
                }

                fclose(fp);
            }
            break;
            case 4:

            exit(0);
            break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Да уж. Це++ -- на удивление мощный и красивый язык. php отдыхает.

Comment: Эээ... Вы хотите, чтобы мы прочитали _весь_ ваш код? Может быть, не поленитесь и выкиньте нерелевантные куски? Минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему, был бы весьма кстати.

ЗЫ: не верится мне что-то, что выделение памяти работает неправильно.

Comment: Действительно, такую простыню не очень хочется перебирать. Выкиньте кусок, где падает, а там разберемся

Answer (score 2):

Какая-то у Вас странная смесь C с C++. Если уж используете вкусности плюсов, такие как перегрузка операторов, выкиньте из кода использование С-style строк (те которые `char *`) и замените их на `std::string`. В этом случае можно будет не думать о длине строки и следовательно не надо будет самостоятельно выделять/освобождать память. Код станет гораздо лаконичнее и понятнее.